# How to refresh wordpress plugin in a period of time that i selected?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a plugin for wordpress and i want it to refresh in every 3 hours i tried header("refresh:10800;url=example.php") but i couldn't get any result.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could try with javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'example.com' },10800)
```

let us know how you get on in 3 1/2 hours or so...

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten confused between the PHP `header()` function and the HTML HEAD section.

The PHP `header( 'Location: newpage.htm' );` performs an instantaneous redirect to **newpage.htm** (and should be directly followed by a call to `die()`). There is no potential to delay that redirection.

Within the HTML `<head> ... </head>` section, you can use a META Tag to perform a delayed refresh or redirection:

```
<!-- Refresh the Current Page every 10 minutes (600 seconds) //-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">

<!-- Redirect to Another Page with a Delay of 10 minutes (600 seconds) //-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;url=http://anotherserver.com/">
```