# I want to refresh a wordpress website in interval of 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am writing a plugin and want to refresh the widget in 10 sec interval. How to achieve this?

I want to call the  widget function in interval so that the widget refreshes.

Here is the code for the plugin

```
<?php
 // Creating the widget 
class rtk_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'rtk_widget', 

// Widget name will appear in UI
__('Realtime Quote', 'rtk_widget_domain'), 

// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'Displays Realtime share quote', 'rtk_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}

// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
$stk_options = get_option('stk_settings');


    //echo "ssss";
    if(is_array($stk_options)&&$stk_options['enable']==1)
    {
        $symbols=  explode(" ", $stk_options['stock-names']);
        foreach ($symbols as $symbol) {

        $quote = fetch('GET', $symbol);
        //var_dump($quote[0]);
        echo '<span class="realtime-company">'.$quote[0]->t.' </span>'.'<span class="realtime-quote">'.$quote[0]->l.'</span>';          

        }           
    }   


// This is where you run the code and display the output

echo $args['after_widget'];
}


// Widget Backend 

public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'New title', 'rtk_widget_domain' );
}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
</p>
<?php 
}


// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class rtk_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function rtk_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'rtk_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'rtk_load_widget' );

 ?>
```

Comment: may be this link help you http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/10/25/setinterval-in-php/

Comment: if possible you can use websocket for real time app .

Answer (score 0):

Refresh php page :

```
<?php
    $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Refresh: 5; URL=\"" . $url . "\""); // redirect in 5 seconds
    ?>
```

Refresh a plugin in wordpress [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448856/how-to-refresh-wordpress-plugin-in-a-period-of-time-that-i-selected)

Comment: Yes but i want to reload the widget only

Answer (score -1):

You cant reload a part of the page from php, you will have to reload the whole page. But i think thats not what you want. You should use ajax to reload the script every 5 seconds.